# Filepath with Spaces as Java Argument

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is,

```
r.exec("xdg-open "+args[1]+"/QRCode.png");
```

But it doesn't work as expected if `args[1]` contains white spaces. I know in case of shell script it can be resolved by using `"$path"`. But I need the solution for Java.

Comment: What is `r`? `Runtime`?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're running this on a UNIX-based system, but could you confirm that?

Comment: You could use `String.replaceAll()` to replace all spaces with `"\ "`.

Comment: @AaronD You probably mean `"\\ "`, but in any case that won't work if `r` is `Runtime`, as `StringTokenizer` does not support escapes. Also, the underlying platform shouldn't affect the technique here.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your path in quotes:

```
r.exec("xdg-open \""+args[1]+"/QRCode.png\"");
```

Comment: That won't work if `r` is a `Runtime`, as, [according to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)), the string is broken with a default `StringTokenizer`, which does not care about quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `r` is a `Runtime`, for that you'll have to use the version of `exec` that takes a `String[]` argument array, to ensure that the string with spaces is treated as a single argument, e.g.:

```
r.exec(new String[]{"xdg-open", args[1]+"/QRCode.png"});
```

While you may be tempted to just pass one string with quotes as the shell does, the `String` version of `Runtime.exec` [uses a default `StringTokenizer` to break up the string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)), which does not recognize quoted strings.

`Runtime`s use of `StringTokenizer` is why your original attempt fails, as it's just blindly divided at spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Runtime.exec()`, use a `ProcessBuilder`:

```
final Path path = Paths.get(args[1], "QRCode.png").toAbsolutePath();

final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("xdg-open", path.toString());

final Process p = pb.start();
```

Also, if this is from the command line, don't forget to quote the arguments...

This:

```
$ foo a b
```

is command `foo` with two arguments, `a` and `b`; this:

$ foo "a b"

is command `foo` with one argument, `a b`.

Comment: While `ProcessBuilder` is always the better solution (and your use of `Path` is great advice), it would also be helpful to expand this answer with a note about why the current attempt isn't working.

Comment: @JasonC fixed for both remarks

Comment: @JasonC I was mentioning the case where the arguments were entered from the command prompt

Comment: You mean `java Foo "a b"`?